# Create a new Google contact using a url request?

Tags: google-contacts-api

Is there a simpler way to add new contacts through a URL request, something like this:

> https://google.contacts.com/new_contact?App_Name=myapp&Id=myId&password=mypwd&name=newUserName&email=newuser@email.com...

I think this was asked some years ago... maybe someone found a way! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the officially documented way of [creating a contact](https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3/#creating_contacts):

**Creating contacts**
To create a new contact, send an authorized POST request to the user's contacts feed URL with contact data in the body.

The URL is of the form:

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{userEmail}/full
```

With the appropriate value in place of userEmail.

Note: The special userEmail value default can be used to refer to the authenticated user.
Upon success, the server responds with an HTTP 201 Created status code and the created contact entry with some additional elements and properties (shown in bold) that are set by the server, such as id, various link elements and properties.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same need, came across this post, and then figured out a little bit through trial and error.

This URL works to take a person to a "new contact" page, with the email and phone pre-populated:

```
https://contacts.google.com/u/0/new?hl=en&email=person@example.com&phone=123-4567
```

[image]

I couldn't figure out how to get the First Name or Last Name to populate - tried all kinds of variations for the query params, maybe someone else will figure that part out.